# TCP/IP quits after 48 hours

Tags: networking, tcp-ip, sco

I have a problem with a (remote) server running SCO UNIX.  It's been working for years, but was recently moved, and I changed its IP address & gateway address.  Since then it works perfectly until after EXACTLY 48 hours, other machines can't connect to it through the network, and can't ping it.  The server also can't ping any other machines or the gateway on the network.  Everything is done by IP address (no DNS issues).  The server continues to function normally otherwise.  I tried replacing the network switch to no avail.  Restarting the server fixes everything for 48 hours.

Comment: interesting timeframe; is there DHCP involved?

Comment: Are you sure the IP is unique? I had a similar problem once caused by ARP collisions, but 48 hours is rather long

Comment: Just TCP or all IP? How precise are your timings?

Comment: VPNs involved? Firewalls